# Problem with moving large population to fixed position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently experiencing an issue with setting large population of GameObjects to a fixed position, or reseting local position. Objects are placed properly on the first frame, but then they start to scatter in somewhat circular way in first frames after they have been placed there. The objects are supposed to be moving in random direction but I have made their first 5 directions in vector list to be exact. Even then they are behaving like in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba88R.png), which is simply not possible for 600 objects to be in 9 locations. Objects have colliders, but colision between themselves is disabled on the rigidbody collision layer.

```cs
private void ResetScene()
    {
        if (algorithmEnabled)
        {
            playerCounter = size;
            Algorithm();
        }
        else
            playerCounter = 1;   
        for(int i = 0; i < circles.Length; i++)
        {
            circles[i].transform.position = circlePos[i];
        }
        foreach(GameObject g in players)
        {
            g.transform.position = parent.transform.position;
            g.transform.localPosition = Vector2.zero;
            g.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
```

Algorithm() function is basically whole GA logic that I implemented, and circles[] are moving object that kill upon collision.

What I need is that those object initial location is always identical, because otherwise the algorithm is useless - agents won't learn the path and will not improve.

I am using Unity 2018.3.3 and its a 2d project.

Comment: So what's your question? I doesn't find a question mark in the title or content.

Comment: How do i make the position of an object exact after I reset its position? Now objects are moving away from each other even though they shouldn't.

Comment: Did you try to set their velocity to zero after you position them? It might do the trick, because how is it sound its a physics reaction...

Comment: Set transform's position should work, you need to check the physical components and scripts to ensure they don't modify the object's position by change.